# A functional equation problem: $f(f(x))=x^2-x+1$

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, functional-equations

I have found this functional equation problem in here
https://gonitzoggo.com/archive/problem/423/english
This problem states that

> for a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$,
> $$f(f(x))=x^2-x+1$$
> Upon these given conditions, find the sum $f(1971)$+$f(50)$+$f(2021)$.

I've made some progress by setting
$$f(f(f(x)))=f(f(f(x)))$$
$$\implies f(x^2-x+1)=f(x)^2-f(x)+1$$
Plugging in $x=1$, after solving the equation $f(1)=f(1)^2-f(1)+1$, we find that $f(1)=1$.

As the equation's discriminant, $x^2-x+1$ is negative, so $f(x)\ge0   \;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Also, I've found that $f(0)$ is either $0$ or $1$.

Can anyone help me to  find  the full solution  for the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do there exist functions $f$ such that $f(f(x))=x^2-x+1$ for every $x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158619/do-there-exist-functions-f-such-that-ffx-x2-x1-for-every-x)

Comment: Related: "[Do there exist functions $f$ such that $f(f(x))=x^2-x+1$ for every $x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1158619/229831)", "[How much does $(f \circ f)(x)=x^2 - x + 1$ determine $f$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2254594/229831)" and "[If $f(f(x))=x^2-x+1$, what is $f(0)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1996141/229831)". Apparently, the problem of proving $ f ( 0 ) = 1 $ has originally appeared as Problem 5 of Baltic Way 2011 contest. The same question posted recently: "[Functional Equation - $f(f(x)) = x^2 - x + 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4363868/229831)".