# If $f(f(x))=x^2-x+1$, what is $f(0)$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Suppose that $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ without any further restriction. If $f(f(x))=x^2-x+1$, how can one find $f(0)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: figure out $f(1)$ first.

Comment: (-1) for showing no effort and/or context in the question.

Comment: Same question on AOPS: "[2019 Nepal National Mathematics Olympiad](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2303094p18233602)", "[Determine f(0) if given f(f(x))](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h443695p2498519)" and "[hard functional equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1115547p5104444)". It seems that the problem has originally appeared as Problem 5 of Baltic Way 2011 contest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We have that

$$f(f(f(x)))=f(x)^2-f(x)+1.$$ Since $f(f(0))=1$ we get that $$f(1)=f(0)^2-f(0)+1.$$ That is

$$f(0)^2-f(0)+1-f(1)=0.$$ Repeating the process, since $f(f(1))=1$ we get that $$f(1)=f(1)^2-f(1)+1.$$ That is

$$(f(1)-1)^2=f(1)^2-2f(1)+1=0.$$ Thus, $f(1)=1.$ So it is $$f(0)^2=f(0),$$ from where $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1.$

If $f(0)=0$ then $f(f(0))=f(0)=0$ which contradicts $f(f(0))=1.$ So, it must be $f(0)=1.$

Answer (score 7):

$f(f(0))=f(f(1))=1$. Apply $f$ once again: $f(f(f(0)))=f(f(f(1)))=f(1)=f(0)^2-f(0)+1=f(1)^2-f(1)+1$.
That leads to $f(1)=1$, hence $f(0)^2-f(0)=0$ and $f(0)$ can only be $0$ or $1$.
But $f(0)=0$ leads to $f(f(0))=0$, contra $f(f(0))=1$, so $\color{red}{f(0)=1}$.

Answer (score 4):

If such a function $f$ exists, then $f(0) = 1$, <strike>but such a function $f$ does not exist</strike>. See the paper:

- *[When is $f(f(x)) = az^2 +bz+c$?](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2321556)*
  R. E. Rice, B. Schweizer and A. Sklar
  The American Mathematical Monthly
  Vol. 87, No. 4 (Apr., 1980), pp. 252-263
  ([Link to PDF not behind the JSTOR paywall](http://yaroslavvb.com/papers/rice-when.pdf))

**Edit**: Such a function does not exist in $\mathbb{C}$! Or in any algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. But you can have such a function in the reals. See the *epilogue* of the paper (page 262).

Comment: Actually the result there is "heavily domain dependent" and in fact they show a quadratic that has arbitrary iterative roots over the reals.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. I just read the introduction and assumed that if it was true in $\mathbb{C}$ then it must be true in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Not true because the way the subset relation works.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is more easy from what it seems. You know that 
$$f(f(0))=1,$$
then
$$f(1)=f(f(f(0)))=f(0)^2-f(0)+1,\;(*)$$
but also
$$f(f(1))=1^2-1+1=1,$$
so
$$f(1)=f(f(f(1)))=f(1)^2-f(1)-1$$
and you can calculate $f(1)$ from here, and then substitute its value in $(*)$