# Proof showing if $f(\frac{3x-2}{2})=x^2-x-1,$ find $f(0)=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, proof-explanation, intuition, functional-equations

PS: Before posting it, one tried to grasp [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996141/if-ffx-x2-x1-what-is-f0) (although didn't understand mfl's answer completely either).

I was shown the way to solve it: if I set $$\frac{3x-2}{2}=0 \Rightarrow x=\frac{2}{3} \Rightarrow x^2-x-1=-\frac{11}{9}$$ that answer will also be the one of $f(0)$ (i.e. $f(0)=-11/9$), which is true, but I don't quite get it: how the answer of $f(\frac{3x-2}{2})$ (i.e. $-11/9$) is also the answer of $f(0)$? why the answer of the quad equ. is also the answer of $f(0)$ (that it is $f(0)=-11/9$)? I asked the person who solved it for me if there was a proof for this, but she couldn't bring it. So, I would be very happy and obliged if someone here would show the proof that it is $f(0)=-11/9$.

Comment: For what it's worth, the question you linked to needs to be solved a bit differently than this one.

Answer (score 2):

substituting $$t=\frac{3x-2}{3}$$ then we get
$$x=\frac{2t+2}{3}$$ then we get
$$f(t)=\left(\frac{2t+2}{3}\right)^2-\frac{2+2t}{3}-1$$ then we get ...?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To calculate $f(0)$ given an expression for $f((3x-2)/2)$, you could find the value of $x$ that makes the argument zero, and then use that value in the expression.

Comment: yes, I knew that but I meant why the answer of the quad equ. is also the answer of $f(0)$?

Comment: I don't think that's true. The right side is an expression for $f((3x-2)/2)$, not $f(x)$.

Comment: Put another way, $x=2/3$ gives you the solution for $f(0)$, because $(3x-2)/2 = 0$ when $x=2/3$.